# How to access the value of a key-value pair within an array variable in Jmeter?

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

I have extracted this variable (userID_ALL) that contains the key-value pairs of some users. I would like to make a foreach loop that will call an API that will use the ID of each user. Is there a way to access the ID of the user in the foreach loop from the varible?

[extracted key-value pairs from Json Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AEpG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there should be a better way to get the IDs from the response, however if you have to deal with the variables as per your screenshot - you could fetch the "id" attribute value using the following __groovy() function:

```
${__groovy(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('userID')).id,)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonSlurper Documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!